# How do I tell D3 to make the dendrogram vertical (top down) instead of left to right?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm looking at [this example](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/cluster.html) that uses cluster layout to assign the X and Y coordinates to nodes on a dendrogram. How can I tell [cluster](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Cluster-Layout#wiki-cluster) to layout vertically, top down, instead of the default left to right?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the [example](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/cluster.html) you link, just flip the use of the X and Y coordinates. This can be done by changing

```
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
  .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });
```

and

```
var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
  .data(nodes)
 .enter().append("g")
   .attr("class", "node")
   .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; })
```

to

```
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
  // Flip the values here.
  .projection(function(d) { return [d.x, d.y]; });
```

and

```
var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
   .data(nodes)
 .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  // Flip the values here.
  .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
```

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brantolsen/Ld6Uz/) showing the above changes in action.

Comment: Depending on your width and height, I also had to change `tree.size([h, w])` to `tree.size([w, h])`