# d3 - create dendrogram - influence of sub-branch depth

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, data-visualization, dendrogram

I wanted to create a dendrogram as presented in this [example](http://bl.ocks.org/d/2429963/). Whereas my source code ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nTK8K/)) is almost exactly the same, the [output](http://jsfiddle.net/nTK8K/embedded/result/) is less than optimal.

I did changed the orientation (as [described](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11480191/how-do-i-tell-d3-to-make-the-dendrogram-vertical-top-down-instead-of-left-to-r) here) and I do not load the json via a json xhr, but create it on the server and write it out to the document (saving one json xhr call).

In the end I do not understand why it is not rendered correctly. I have the following questions:

1. How can I influence the x and y position of the nodes?
2. Is it possible to set the distance between the node levels? The graph as presented now has a very wide distance between each level, say between 0, 1, 1.1, etc levels.
3. Why are the nodes which should be on the same level not rendered at the same level? For example in my fiddle the node **2 - my second wp** is not placed on the same level as the node **1 - my first wp** ?

I have the feeling as it has something to do with my json, but for me it looks correct.

Adding more nodes it is getting even more confuse:

[Source](http://jsfiddle.net/sWGgP/) and [Result](http://jsfiddle.net/sWGgP/embedded/result/)

Would appreciate any help.

Edit:

A bit more insight:

I found out that in order that child nodes from the same level are rendered on the same level their sub-branches have to have the same depth. See this fiddle ([source](http://jsfiddle.net/7Pq5y/1/), [result](http://jsfiddle.net/7Pq5y/1/embedded/result/)) for same depth, and see this fiddle ([source](http://jsfiddle.net/rJrNP/), [result](http://jsfiddle.net/rJrNP/embedded/result/)) for different depth and as a result, child "optimization" is rendered one level deeper. I would have expected that child "optimization" is rendered at the same level as "cluster" and "graph".

Any way to work around this behavior?

Comment: I found an example which does create a nice tree with having different depths. I think this is exactly what I m looking for: http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111018/tree.html